# Laravel 5 Socialite - change auth redirect path dynamically

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-socialite

I am trying to incorporate Socialite into a site and have come across a problem with what should be a rather trivial thing to do - change where the user is redirected after authenticated by a social provider.

I have three actions that I will be using Socialite for:

- **Register** - Authenticate with the provider and then redirect to the Registration Form. Their name and email address are filled in for them, more fields are required.
- **Login** - Typical login scenario, the provider information is checked against the Users table and they are logged in if there is a match
- **Link** - User already has an active account but would like to link an external (Faceebook or Google) account. This authenticates the user and adds the proper social media ID to their row in the Users table.
  The problem is that you specify the authentication redirect in the services.php file, I cannot figure out how to change where the user is redirected after successfully authenticating with the third party provider.

Here is what I have so far -

Route: This seems to work up to when the social provider redirects, because `driver=facebook&action=login` (for example) is missing. Ideally, I'd like to specify where the user is redirected when the initial auth request is made - this was just my first attempt at figuring this out.

```
get('social-auth', function(AuthenticateUser $authenticateUser, Request $request) {
    $driver = $request->input('driver');
    $action = $request->input('action');

    return $authenticateUser->execute($request->has('code'), $driver, $action);
});
```

AuthenticateUser class - Hopefully the comments here are sufficient:

```
<?php namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException;
use Laravel\Socialite\Contracts\Factory as Socialite;
use Auth;
use Flash;

class AuthenticateUser
{
    /**
     * @var Socialite
     */
    private $socialite;
    /**
     * @var Auth
     */
    private $auth;

    public function __construct(Socialite $socialite, Auth $auth)
    {

        $this->socialite = $socialite;
        $this->auth = $auth;
    }

    /**
     * @param boolean $hasCode Whether or not we have been authenticated already
     * @param string $driver Driver to use, Facebook or Google
     * @param string $type Type of call - Login, Register, or Link
     * @return array|\Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse|\Illuminate\Routing\Redirector
     */
    public function execute($hasCode, $driver, $type)
    {
        if (!$hasCode) {
            return $this->getAuthorizationFirst($driver);
        }

        // Get the User details from the Social Provider
        $socialUser = $this->socialite->driver($driver)->user();
        $socialUserArray = $socialUser->user;

        if ($driver == 'facebook') {
            // Get Facebook specific fields
            $first_name = $socialUserArray['first_name'];
            $last_name = $socialUserArray['last_name'];
        } else if ($driver == 'google') {
            // Get Google specific fields
            $first_name = $socialUserArray['name']['givenName'];
            $last_name = $socialUserArray['name']['familyName'];
        }
        $email = $socialUser->email;
        $id = $socialUser->id;

        // Perform an action - login, register, or link
        switch ($type) {
            case 'login':
                // Log the user in with the Facebook ID
                try {
                    if ($driver == 'facebook') {
                        $user = User::whereFacebookAuth($id)->firstOrFail();
                    } else {
                        $user = User::whereGoogleAuth($id);
                    }
                } catch (ModelNotFoundException $e) {
                    flash::error('Could not find a user associated with this ' . ucfirst($driver) . ' account.');
                    return redirect('auth/login');
                }
                Auth::login($user);
                return redirect('members');
                break;
            case 'register':
                // Register using social media account
                return redirect('register')
                    ->with('social_type', $driver)
                    ->with('social_id', $id)
                    ->with('email', $email)
                    ->with('first_name', $first_name)
                    ->with('last_name', $last_name);
                break;
            case 'link':
                // Associate this Social Media account with the current User
                $driver == 'facebook' ? Auth::user()->facebook_auth = $id : Auth::user()->google_auth = $id;
                Auth::user()->save();
                return ['status' => 'success'];
                break;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Authorize the user before proceeding
     * @param $driver
     * @return mixed
     */
    private function getAuthorizationFirst($driver)
    {
        return $this->socialite->with($driver)->redirect('hopefully-somewhere-else'); 
    // Anything inside redirect doesn't seem to do anything
    }
}
```

Comment: We went a completely different direction on this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/42352903/186782

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tend to include the provider in my URLs. For example:

```php
Route::get('auth/{provider}', 'AuthController@redirectToProvider');
Route::get('auth/{provider}/callback', 'AuthController@handleProviderCallback');
```

That way I can access the provider name from the request in my controller actions:

```php
public function callback($provider)
{
    $user = $this->socialite->driver($provider)->getUser();

    try {
        // Try and find user by their social profile UID
        $appUser = SocialAccount::whereUid($user->getId())
            ->whereProvider($provider)
            ->firstOrFail();

        Auth::loginUsingId($appUser->user_id);
    } catch (ModelNotFoundException $e) {
        if (Auth::user()) {
            // Attach social profile to logged in user
        } else {
            // User is not logged in, and account does not exist
            // Prompt to register
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but the provider part isn't the biggest problem, it's handling multiple actions - logging in, registering, and linking (as described in the question). The only thing I can think of is to have a driver for each in services.php with a redirect path for each (login, register, link) but there has to be a better way

Comment: You would normally have one callback that checks if the third-party account has been used to sign in and if so, just logs the corresponding user in. If not and the user is logged in attach the social account to their profile. Otherwise, provide a registration form (with data pre-filled from social profile) and fields to capture any other information necessary for your website.

Comment: This is a highly restricted site so all new members must be approved prior to logging in (security requirement). If the user clicks on "Register with <Social Provider>" they will be prompted to authorize the site and then be redirected to the registration form with their details pre-filled into the form. If they already have an active account I want them to be able to link a social account later on. The third scenario is simply logging in. So I need to have multiple redirect paths to my app to handle these different scenarios.

Comment: Also, the user's email address on my site may not (and probably will not) match that of their chosen social provider - so I am going based on their user ID rather than email as reported by the provider. This is why I need to have this information for registration and linking later on.

Comment: Yes, you would store the profile UID against your site’s user ID. So if I authenticated with Facebook, you would store my Facebook profile ID against my user ID. That way, any subsequent authentication requests you will know are for my user account. You would have to use UIDs any way, as Twitter doesn’t expose users’ email addresses via their API.

Comment: Okay, the problem is redirecting to different endpoints in my app to handle the three different tasks - if I only wanted to log users in, that's a piece of cake. Any thoughts on how I can handle the redirect? I am only working with Facebook and Google, both allow for multiple redirect paths.

Comment: Again, you would have a single callback that determines whether or not to login, register, or link the account. I’ve updated my answer to illustrate this.

Comment: *facepalm* Why didn't I think of that? Thanks bro :)

Comment: Ha-ha, no worries. Glad to have helped.

Answer (score 3):

Late to join party but may help out others. If you want to handle multiple redirection like login, register, link social account to user profile, that can be done by overriding service config from your controller side.

```
config(['services.google.redirect' => <Your New URL here> ]);
Socialite::driver('google')->redirect();
```

Note :- There are some social platforms that strictly requires to mention redirects URL into their developer console. So you need to mentioned each redirect URL there.